# Trying to execute vue js webpack simple application

Tags: npm, vue.js

I am trying to execute an application in `vue.js` but I am getting some warnings, that I don´t understand. I am using the `webpack-simple` template in `vue.js`. I attached a screenshot of the warnings; please tell me what those warning mean.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE37X.jpg]

Comment: Nothing really important - you app should work propely even with this warnings.